.containerignore not work when I am outside of the folder
I have a project:
.
├── protesta
│   ├── back
│   │   └── app
│   │       └── .containerfile
│   └── front
│   |   └── app
│   │       └── .containerfile

I use the following commands to build and run the containers:
podman build --rm -f protesta/back/containerfile -t pro_back 
podman run -d --replace -p 8000:8000 --label "io.containers.autoupdate=local" --name pro_back pro_back:latest

podman build --rm -f protesta/front/containerfile -t pro_front
podman run -d --replace -p 9010:9010 --label "io.containers.autoupdate=local" --name pro_front pro_front:latest

The problem I'm encountering is that when I build the images, the .containerignore file and the files it should exclude (e.g., .git*) are still being included in the images.
How can I ensure that the .containerignore file is respected and that the specified files are excluded from the images during the build process?

Move .containerignore to app folder > not work
Move .containerignore to root folder (front/back) here is where containerfile is > Not Work
Try using --ignorefile > not work.

